# Choose Bootstrap option with capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, cucumber, capybara

I'm having problems selecting an option with Capybara in a form made with Bootstrap and I don't know why.

This is how the form is actually written:

```
<div class="control-group radio_buttons optional application_read">   
  <label class="radio_buttons optional control-label">Read</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <span class="radio">
      <label for="application_read_true">
        <input class="radio_buttons optional" type="radio" value="true" name="application[read]" id="application_read_true">Yes
      </label>
    </span>
    <span class="radio">
      <label for="application_read_false">
        <input class="radio_buttons optional" type="radio" value="false" checked="checked" name="application[read]" id="application_read_false">No
      </label>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I'm attempting to do is select the first Radio button with "Yes" label (so Read: Yes) this way:

```
  find("#application_read_true").click
```

but it doesn't affect the form in any way.
How can I select the True option under the 'Read' label? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
choose("application_read_true")
```

But I believe that this should work too if you have only one radio button with "Yes" caption

```
choose("Yes")
```

Comment: Ahhhhh! I didn't try the simplest thing! Thanks!